# Fixed List header with React Virtuoso

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-virtuoso

We can add a custom header to the list by using the `components` property of React virtuoso. ([Link](https://virtuoso.dev/virtuoso-api-reference/))

But can the header also be configured to be fixed? (always at the top of the scroll container) How?

[This feature seems to exist for tables](https://virtuoso.dev/table-fixed-headers/), but I need it for lists.

I will work around this for now [using the `topItemCount` property](https://virtuoso.dev/top-items/), but this feels rather hacky. Looking for the "intended" solution here.